# Is there a way to restrict untrusted container scheduler?

Tags: security, docker, containers

I have an application which I'd like to give the privilege to launch short-lived tasks and schedule these as docker containers. I was thinking of doing this simply via `docker run`.

As I want to make the attack surface as small as possible, I treat the application as untrusted. As such it can potentially run arbitrary `docker run` commands (if the codebase contained bug or the container was compromised, input was improperly escaped somewhere etc.) against a predefined docker API endpoint.

This is why I'd like to restrict that application (effectively a scheduler) in some ways:

- prevent `--privileged` use
- enforce `--read-only` flag
- enforce memory & CPU limits

---

I looked at couple of options:

- selinux

  - the selinux policies would need to be set on the host level and then propagated inside the containers via `--selinux-enabled` flag on the `daemon` level. The scheduler can however override this anyway via `run --privileged`.
- seccomp profiles

  - these are only applied at a time of launching the container (seccomp flags are available for `docker run`)
- AppArmor

  - this can (again) be overriden on the scheduler level via `--privileged`
- docker daemon `--exec-opts` flag

  - only a single option is actually available for this flag (`native.cgroupdriver`)

It seems that Docker is designed to trust container schedulers by default.
Does anyone know if this is a design decision?

Is there any other possible solution available w/ current latest Docker version that I missed?

---

I also looked at Kubernetes and its [Limit Ranges](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/docs/design/admission_control_limit_range.md) & [Resource Quotas](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/docs/design/admission_control_resource_quota.md) which can be applied to K8S namespaces, which looked interesting, assuming there's a way to enforce certain schedulers to only use certain namespaces. This would however increase the scope of this problem to operating K8S cluster.

Comment: I would argue that "untrusted" and "able to run arbitrary commands" are inherently contradictory. Are you allowing them to actually run any command, and just expecting it to be a `docker run` command? Or are you allowing them to specify a string of arguments to `docker run`? If the second, why not just modify the `docker run` prefix to add the `--privileged=false` and `--read-only` flags? A command that specifies a second `--privileged` argument should fail

Comment: It is explicitely stated in the docs that only trusted users should be allowed to control the daemon. So it's unlikely that you have missed much (except perhaps for user namespaces which could be interesting) I would suggest creating a launcher shell script with sudo perms that runs container with the restrictions you want, not giving your "untrusted" application full control over `docker run` arguments.

Comment: @F.StephenQ I explained above that "able to run arbitrary commands" is not something I expect to happen "by design", but rather by accident (e.g. app compromised or improper escaping).

Answer (score 1):

running docker on a unix platform should be compatible with [`nice`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/unice.htm)  Or so I would think at first looking a little more closely it looks like you need somethign like  [`-cpuset-cpus="0,1"`](https://lime-technology.com/forum/index.php?topic=42126.0)

From the second link , **"The --cpu-quota looks to be similar to the --cpuset-cpus ... allocate one or a few cores to a process, it's just time managed instead of processor number managed."**