# Is it possible to prevent RedHat/CentOS Docker host root access from within a container?

Tags: security, docker

I want to provide a minimal CentOS/RedHat VM to a staff member to log into using a non-root user account.  I made the docker socket available to the user to run docker 1.12 cli commands via chgrping the socket and adding the account into the docker group.

Assuming we leave the TCP API, and all CaaS/PaaS products out of this question, on a VM, is it possible using SELinux, manipulation of seccomp and/or linux capabilities or anything else (including GRSec/PAX) to prevent the use of Docker containers to access the root user on the Docker host?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965576/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-untrusted-container-scheduler) appears not to turn up a definitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are exposing your host's Docker socket to the container, then you've essentially given them root privileges to the host.

If you are trying to provide an isolated Docker environment within a container, you should use Docker-in-Docker. See the `dind` tagged images for the [`docker` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/). This is how [Play with Docker](http://play-with-docker.com/) works.

Comment: By 'essentially' exactly what do you mean?

Comment: He means absolutely. If you have access to the Docker socket (so, can you run docker?), then you are root.